# onLoad not been called in lightning:recordEditForm

Tags: lightning, aura, lightning-record-form

I am having input fields inside my recordEditForm. When i try to run the component it's not calling the onload event handler. I don't want to put any lightning:inputField into it. Because I don't need standard UI. Also receiving error on submit.Here is my sample code.

**newContact.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="simpleNewContact" type="Object"/>
    <lightning:recordEditForm
            onload="{!c.handleLoad}"
            onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}" 
            onerror="{!c.handleError}"
            onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
            objectApiName="Contact" aura:id="myRecordForm">
        <div class="Create Contact">
            <lightning:card iconName="action:new_contact" title="Create Contact">
                <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
                    <lightning:input aura:id="contactField" label="First Name" value="{!v.simpleNewContact.FirstName}"/>
                    <lightning:input aura:id="contactField" label="Last Name" value="{!v.simpleNewContact.LastName}"/>
                    <lightning:input aura:id="contactField" label="Title" value="{!v.simpleNewContact.Title}"/>
                    <br/>
                    <lightning:button label="Save Contact" type="submit" variant="brand"/>
                </div>
            </lightning:card>
        </div>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>

    <!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.newContactError))}">
        <div class="recordError">
            {!v.newContactError}</div>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

**newContactController.js**

```
({
    handleLoad : function(component, evnet, helper){
        console.log('loaded');
    },
    handleSuccess : function(component, evnet, helper){
        var payload = event.getParams().response;
        alert(payload.id);
    },
    handleError:function(component, evnet, helper){
        var error = event.getParam('error');
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    },
    handleSubmit : function(component, evnet, helper){
        event.preventDefault();   
        var fields = event.getParam('fields');
        console.log(fields);
        component.find("myRecordForm").submit(component.get("v.simpleNewContact"));
    }
})
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the "standard UI", use force:recordData instead. You can load and save records using this component without requiring a UI.

Comment: here is what I faced in force:recordData before moving into this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262811/handling-success-save-event-for-lds-new-record?noredirect=1#comment397879_262811

Comment: @Rajesh force:recordData is more likely the correct method, but your other question will need to be solved. I don't have a mobile setup at the moment, so I don't think I have an answer to the situation, but hopefully you'll find the answer you need.